# How can I list installed printers on client side? 

Tags: asp.net, printing

I have a web application. I list of local installed printers on a computer but when application runs from server it lists printers on server. I need the list of local printers. how can I do that??

Comment: You can't (without having to deploy a browser plugin) - all you can do by default is invoke the print command and then let the browser take over.

Comment: @Damien: post that as the answer.